# Not enough permissions to access: GET /fieldsOfStudy

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to call `LinkedIn` V2 API to call a specific API which is:

> GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/fieldsOfStudy

So I followed the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfof_ha0WGM) to create an application, linked it with my account on `LinkedIn` and verify it.
Everything worked fine and I have an Access Token.

But I'm always having the following response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /fieldsOfStudy",
    "status": 403
}
```

And here are the permissions in my app:

> OAuth 2.0 scopes
>
> Permissions your app can request from users
>
> r_emailaddress
>
> r_liteprofile
>
> w_member_social